# How to restrict who can obtain a valid access token?

Tags: symfony, oauth, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I've developed an APIRest service to consume data from a mobile app. I've used the Symfony2 bundles: FOSOAuthServerBundle, FOSUserBundle and FOSRestBundle and all work fine but I need to differenciate the admin panel users and the api users because now if I try to authenticate with an admin from app, I will obtain a token however I only want to get a valid one with api users.

For example, with the next users I should get a valid token with the second request and an invalid grant response with the first but I obtain a valid token with both of them:

**adminuser (ROLE_ADMIN)**

https://app.myweb.com/oauth/v2/token?username=adminuser&password=12345&client_id=...&client_secret=...&grant_type=password

**appuser (ROLE_APP)**

https://app.myweb.com/oauth/v2/token?username=appuser&password=12345&client_id=...&client_secret=...&grant_type=password

Thanks a lot for put me on the correct way to solve this and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

From FOSOAuthServerBundle documentation:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-fosoauthserverbundle

Create a user provider and add it to the fos_oauth_server configuration:

```
fos_oauth_server:
    ...
    service:
        user_provider: my_custom_user_provider_service
```

Create provider extending the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface interface and check if user has the ROLE_APP granted. Documented here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html